# Dynamic indenting of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've created a nested list, dropdown menu.

Problem: The CSS is only handling 1 level of nested menus. I can't figure out how to set the position of nested items so it can handle multiple levels without me having to set those rules in a CSS file.

This is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uoydnc8h/4/) I've been working with

The CSS:

```
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed few rules in your css:

```
ul li:hover > ul { /* I just added ">" so it affect's only next ul. */
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

ul ul li > ul { /* This will fix the position for children uls */
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/xwazzo/pk7kcqb9/

Comment: That is a smart idea to position the children.

Comment: Thanks @sabithpocker ! I will leave this link to [Horizontal submenus for a vertical main menu post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349002/horizontal-submenu-for-a-vertical-main-menu-using-bootstrap/36349902#36349902) here because I think related and it's well explained.

Comment: Damn, I thought in an anchor link inside the `li` and it messed everything up

Comment: If you have the live example or more details I can help you. @Batman

Comment: It's okay, I ended up figuring it out. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try using [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `a > b` instead of [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) `a b`.

You may not need child selectors everywhere, for the common styles you can make use of the descendant selectors itself, I just used it *everywhere*, and it may not be the right way for you!

```js
var items = [{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Menu A",
  "link": "http: //www.google.com"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "title": "Menu B",
  "link": "http://www.google.com"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "title": "Menu C",
  "link": "http://www.google.com"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "title": "Menu D",
  "link": "http://www.google.com"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "title": "Menu E",
  "link": "http://www.google.com"
}, {
  "id": "6",
  "title": "Menu 1A",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "1;#Menu A"
}, {
  "id": "7",
  "title": "Menu 2A",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "1;#Menu A"
}, {
  "id": "8",
  "title": "Menu 3A",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "1;#Menu A"
}, {
  "id": "9",
  "title": "Menu 1B",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "2;#Menu B"
}, {
  "id": "10",
  "title": "Menu 2B",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "2;#Menu B"
}, {
  "id": "11",
  "title": "Menu 1C",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "3;#Menu C"
}, {
  "id": "12",
  "title": "Menu 2C",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "3;#Menu C"
}, {
  "id": "13",
  "title": "Menu 3C",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "3;#Menu C"
}, {
  "id": "14",
  "title": "Menu 1D",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "4;#Menu D"
}, {
  "id": "15",
  "title": "Menu 2D",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "14;#Menu 1D"
}, {
  "id": "16",
  "title": "Menu 3D",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "15;#Menu 2D"
}, {
  "id": "17",
  "title": "Menu 1E",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "5;#Menu E"
}, {
  "id": "18",
  "title": "Menu 2E",
  "link": "http://www.google.com",
  "parent": "17;#Menu 1E"
}]

items = $.map(items, function(item) {
  return {
    id: item.id,
    title: item.title,
    link: item.link,
    parent: (item.parent) ? item.parent.split(";")[0] : false
  }
})
console.log(items)


var container = $("#container");

(function createMenu() {
  $.each(items, function(i, v) {
    //Check if item has parent
    if (v.parent == false) {
        // Check if container has first level ul
        if (container.find("ul#topLevel").length == 0) {
          container.append($("<ul>").attr("id","topLevel"))
        } else {
          console.log('firstlevel exist')
        }

      //Add items to first level
      container
      .find('ul')
      .append($("<li>")
        .text(v.title)
        .attr('id', v.id)
        )
    }else{
      var parent = v.parent;
      var parentElement = $("#"+parent);

      if( parentElement.find('ul').length == false ) {
        
        parentElement.append($("<ul>").attr({
          id: 'subLevelFor_'+ parent
        }))
      }

      $("ul#subLevelFor_"+ parent)
      .append($("<li>")
        .text(v.title)
        .attr('id', v.id)
        )
    }
  })
  console.log('done')
})();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E3CAA1;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul > li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul > li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul > li > ul > li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul > li > ul > li:hover { background: #666; }
ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not override the tags directly or it will be more complicated for you to expand. Create CSS classes to save your time. If you write the css like this eg: "ul li ul li" it will going to be more complicate in future. And also try to use "ul > li" selector to apply the styles on child. not child of child.